# Why is `which -a ruby` showing wrong path?

Tags: ruby, unix, path, installation

When I do `which -a ruby` I see:

```
/Users/catali/.rbenv/shims//ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

And when I do `echo $PATH` I see:

```
Users/catali/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/bin /Users/catali/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/bin /Users/catali/.rbenv/bin /Users/catali/.rbenv/shims/ /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin
```

I installed `rbenv` and using `fish shell`. In my fish shell I added: `set -x PATH $HOME/.rbenv/bin $PATH`

When I do `ruby -v` it takes a long time, and I think is because the path `/Users/catali/.rbenv/shims//ruby` is wrong, notice the extra `\` before ruby.

How can I know where is that being defined?

Comment: Extra slashes in the path don't really mean much and don't slow anything down. `/` and `////////////////` are the same thing.

Comment: If you're really fussed about this you can edit your path to be `/Users/catali/.rbenv/shims` instead, but it shouldn't matter.

Comment: I don't know fish shell, but like all the other shells, there is likely a `.fish_profile` or `.fishrc` or some config file that controls includes and paths and all other shell-related business.  You should look in that config to see if it is also including a reference to say `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` which may be where `rbenv` has defined PATH statements